# Load razor pages with layout without refreshing entire page

Tags: .net-6.0, razor-pages, visual-studio-2022

I just created a net6.0 Razor Pages project in Visual Studio 2022. I haven't made any changes to it at all.

The layout is the standard file that gets created. Using a nav bar with links to Home/Index and Privacy. I plan on adding a side bar for navigation as well.

All I want to do is, while using _Layout.cshtml, load pages from my nav links (ex: Index, Privacy, etc...) without reloading/refreshing the entire page. I just want to update the main content without reloading everything.

I've been searching online for a few hours and I just can't find what I'm looking for. I'm not sure where to start :(

Comment: You will have to write some javascript, calling `fetch` and replace the elements, you want.

Comment: You can do this idiomatically with Blazor.  Blazor acts like a Single Page Application (SPA).  This is not idiomatic in Razor Pages or MVC which is a web application or multi-page application

Comment: Highly recommend you too look at Blazor, server or wasm, whatever suits you best.

Comment: You can try to use partial view,and update the partial view with js.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without JavaScript. Try SignalR and JavaScript for Razor Pages